# Why can't I add a new trade route even though I have 2 cities and 2 slots available?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I have 2 cities. In my capital, I have 1 out of 2 trade slots occupied. That occupied slot trades with my other city. The other city has 1 trade slot which is also free! So I could have *three* trade routes, yet even not even my second Trade Convoy works. When I try to establish a new trade route, I just can't connect it to any city. Quite infuriating!

The cities are 3 hexes from each other and there's no miasma between them (since the existent trade route works just fine). I'd expect to at least be able to establish 1 trade route from each city to the other, but I can't even do that :(.

Comment: Are you within range? Sometimes cities can be too far away for you to trade with, and if they're over water you'll need a different type of trade convey. Can't remember what it's called though.

Comment: Yes, in range, no miasma. Edited the question :).

Comment: It's been a while since I played, so I could be wrong, but can't a single pair of tiles only support one trade route?  So, if you have three slots total and two cities, you can only spend one slot trading between your own cities and you must spend your other two slots trading with rival cities or independent stations or else let them sit idle.

Comment: I think the max number of trade routes between two cities is 1 (especially from the same starting city). I think it will work if the cities are different nations.

Comment: Have you tried initiating the trade route from the city that hasn't established a route? The [wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Trade_routes_(CivBE)) doesn't cover this, but I suspect @gatherer818 is correct.

Comment: I encountered either this or something similar to this last night. I had cities that previously had plenty of trade routes. Some of the convoys were destroyed in a war, and one surviving convoy had a route interrupted. After the war I went to re-establish it, and the there were no routes available to select. Going into the trade management window and the available routes tab clearly displayed at least 50 different trade routes, but the side panel of the convoy wouldn't list a single one for the city it was in. Having the convoy change cities didn't make a difference, so I deleted the convoy.

Comment: I'll build some new convoys tonight and see if the new ones can see the available routes that the trade management screen clearly says should be available.

Answer (score 1):

It's a balance mechanic. It prevents explosive growth through trade that one could achieve if allowed to create more than one trade route between the same two cites.

Answer (score 0):

Each city can only have one trade route to every other city. Since trade routes benefit both destinations, starting a trade route from either city to the other fills that allowed route in both directions. Neutral stations will even allow only one trade route per faction.

To open more trade routes, you will either have to found another city, discover another faction's cities, or find a neutral station.